# How to group items in a list of dictionaries by matching values in python

Tags: python

I have the following an array of dictionaries:

```
dictionaty =[{'name': 'fire', 'command': '1;2;3;4'}, 
{'name': 'brain', 'command': '2;2;3;4'}, {'name': 'word', 'command': '1;3;4;5'},
{'name': 'cellphone', 'command': '6;1;3;4'}, {'name': 'ocean', 'command': '9;3;7;4'},
```

how do I get the dictionaries that have the command with the second and third value after ';' respectively equal?
For example: 'command': '1;2;3;4' is equals 'command': '2;2;3;4'

Comment: I thought I'd go one by one, but I believe it is computationally infeasible.

Comment: you dictionary is a list

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I see this frequently, it's even funnier in C++ where you have to specify the type, e.g. `float myInt = 5.35;`

Comment: sorry just forgot to announce it was an array of dictionaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). You can construct a `lambda` expression that looks for the value corresponding to the `'command'` key, then finds the `[1]` and `[2]` elements of splitting on the `';'` character.

```
d =[{'name': 'fire', 'command': '1;2;3;4'},
    {'name': 'brain', 'command': '2;2;3;4'},
    {'name': 'word', 'command': '1;3;4;5'},
    {'name': 'cellphone', 'command': '6;1;3;4'},
    {'name': 'ocean', 'command': '9;3;7;4'}]

import itertools
groups = itertools.groupby(d, lambda i: i['command'].split(';')[1:3])

for key, group in groups:
    print(list(group))
```

Output

```
[{'name': 'fire', 'command': '1;2;3;4'}, {'name': 'brain', 'command': '2;2;3;4'}]
[{'name': 'word', 'command': '1;3;4;5'}]
[{'name': 'cellphone', 'command': '6;1;3;4'}]
[{'name': 'ocean', 'command': '9;3;7;4'}]
```

To find groups that had more than one member, you need one more step:

```
for key, group in groups:
    groupList = list(group)
    if len(groupList) > 1:
        print(groupList)

[{'command': '1;2;3;4', 'name': 'fire'}, {'command': '2;2;3;4', 'name': 'brain'}]
```

Comment: But the output is equal to the array in this case, I expect that only the lines  were the result: {'name':'fire','command':'1;2;3;4'}, {'name': 'brain', 'command': '2;2;3;4'}

Comment: Sorry but, what is [1:3] on (d, lambda i: i['command'].split(';')[1:3])?

Comment: I'm taking the string `'1;2;3;4'` and splitting on the `';'`. This will return the list `['1','2','3','4']`. I am using [slice notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation) To get the 2nd and 3rd element, which are at `[1]` and `[2]`. The slice `[1:3]` means `[start:stop]`, but it goes up to "stop" but doesn't include it.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the items and for each item check the items to follow and compare the last part of `'command'`:

```
dictionaty =[{'name': 'fire', 'command': '1;2;3;4'}, 
             {'name': 'brain', 'command': '2;2;3;4'}, 
             {'name': 'word', 'command': '1;3;4;5'},
             {'name': 'cellphone', 'command': '6;1;3;4'}, 
             {'name': 'ocean', 'command': '9;3;7;4'}]

for i, itm in enumerate(dictionaty):
    itm_last_part = itm['command'].split(';')[2:]
    for second in dictionaty[i+1:]:
        second_last_part = second['command'].split(';')[2:]
        if itm_last_part == second_last_part:
            print itm, second, "are equal"
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{'command': '1;2;3;4', 'name': 'fire'} {'command': '2;2;3;4', 'name': 'brain'} are equal
{'command': '1;2;3;4', 'name': 'fire'} {'command': '6;1;3;4', 'name': 'cellphone'} are equal
{'command': '2;2;3;4', 'name': 'brain'} {'command': '6;1;3;4', 'name': 'cellphone'} are equal
```